# How to access my business’ Facebook Page Feed from my web server using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-oauth

I have a pre-existing Facebook Business Page set up on Facebook and I just registered my website (App) on the Facebook Developers Console using the same Business name as the Facebook Page name. I am an admin on both the App account and the Business Page. My app is also on the list of “subscribed apps” for the Page. Even still, Facebook doesn’t see the app and page as the same business, and I still don’t see my page in the “App Pages” section of my App Settings like it says I should.

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to establish a communication between my web server and my Facebook Page in order to READ posts on my page using the Graph API. However, when I try accessing the page node or any of its edges using my App Token (via Graph Explorer OR my web server), it’s telling me I need an App review before I can read the public data on my own Facebook page.

My guess is that this is happening because there is still no established connection between the app and the page... and if that’s the case, what more can I do to make the connection? Anyone have any experience with this?

FYI: I’ve read many other posts on this issue and most of them are outdated or don’t give any clear answers to the question. I feel this question is valid due to the privacy changes introduced by Facebook last March.

Comment: why use an app token? use a page token instead.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: page token doesnt work either. user token works... but obviously I dont want to be using a user access token for server calls. This is the message that I am getting from the graph api when I call my page using a short-lived or long-lived page access token: `(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."`

Comment: all that stuff is pretty new and weird right now. it can indeed be that you need to review usage, and a user token for getting content of your page is definitely not the way to go, i would say.

Comment: I just submitted my app for review. Oh well, it is what it is I suppose :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your App reviewed, older apps work till August 2018. But as now every review takes a month and there is high change that you are not approved for "Page Public Content Access". Reason for approve denial is "it doesn't appear to enhance the user experience". And after that, there is not much you can do. You can make another app and submit it to the review, with info that might pass the review process.

As for now, i do not know the correct phrases to use in review-form, but if some-one gets "Page Public Content Access"-approval, please let us know how.